# How to extract title of each product using python web scraping

Tags: web-scraping, python-requests

Here is the link:https://www.118100.se/sok/foretag/?q=brf&loc=&ob=rel&p=0

```
def get_index_data(soup):
try:
    links = soup.find_all('div','a',id=False).get('href')
except:
    links = []
print(links)
```

Answer (score 0):

Find all `div`, which has `class` name `Name` *(class="Name")*. which gives you all title names. If you want `href` then iterate through all `titles` and find `a` tag which has `title` is text of `title.text`.

```
import requests
import bs4 as bs

url = 'https://www.118100.se/sok/foretag/?q=brf&loc=&ob=rel&p=0'

response = requests.get(url)
# print('Response:', response.status_code)

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
titles = soup.find_all('div',  {'class': 'Name'})

# a = soup.find_all('a')
# print(a)

for title in titles:
    link = soup.find('a',  {'title': title.text}).get('href')
    print('https://www.118100.se' + link)
```

Comment: hi thank you but this code displaying only "response 200" . Could you please modify it that it should only display title link? please sir! @Mrugesh Kadia